# How to retrieve record from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to this site and I need the help for following

person table:

```
driver_id     name     address
1            sankar    karaikal
2            vivek     chennai
3            kumaran   pondy
4            siva      chennai
```

car table

```
license      model       year
22            bmw       2014
23            toyata    2014
24            audi      2015
25            maruti    2014
```

owns table

```
driver_id       license
1                22
2                23
3                24
4                25
```

Question is how to find who owned cars that were involved in accident in 2014.
I need a sql query for this and thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: i dont know how to do this please explain how to do this

Comment: @SankarGanesh: At least write a query that retrieves a row from one of the tables. You should be able to get that far. "Gimme the codez!" questions that don't show *any* effort are generally not well received on StackOverflow. (This is especially true of homework questions.) If you can't write a query that returns rows from a single table, then you really need to get that figured out, before you try writing a query that involves three tables.

Comment: select name,year,license from person p,car c,owns w where p.driver_id=o.driver_id and o.license=c.license and c.year=2014;                                               HELP ME TO CORRECT IT

Comment: If you edit your question with the query you just wrote, that will bump your question back up in the list. Most people aren’t going to notice when you add code down here in the comments. There is an edit link below your post.

Comment: I’m not good enough at SQL to write a query off the top of my head, but I’d recommend looking at tutorials on MySQL joins, and then updating your question as you get closer to getting a working query. Hopefully, someone will come along and help. Maybe try to join just two tables to start with.

Comment: After reading some tutorials and few pages of books i am able to understand it.Its very simple but for me it take several hours to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
select name from person  p
inner join 
owns  o on
(p.driver_id=o.driver_id)
inner join
car c on (c.license=o.license)where year='2014';
```